# Returning generic type from a URLRequest dataTask

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to build a generic function to return an array of a given type once a URLSession's dataTask has completed.

I have this Decodable:

```swift
struct Todo: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool
}
```

And this function:

```swift
func loadFrom<T: Decodable>(url: String, memberType: T, completionHandler: (T?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        completionHandler(nil)
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            fatalError("No data returned")
        }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let results = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)

            completionHandler(results)
        }catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't parse data")
        }
    }.resume()
}

loadFrom(url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?completed=true", memberType: Todo) {response in
    ...
}
```

> error: Swift Scratchpad.playground:61:88: error: argument type 'Todo.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'

I've seen similar issues which point to the compiler being unable to synthesise the methods that the Decodable protocol requires for conformance, but building a similar method which is assigned to the Decodable type rather than having it specified as a parameter works:

```swift
func loadFile<T: Decodable>(file: String) -> T {
...
}

var todos: [Todo] = loadFile(file: "todos.json")
print(todos[0].title) => "The todo title"
```

I assume the fact that my `loadFrom` doesn't have its return type specified is the cause, but I don't understand why. 
Would it be possible to provide enough context for this code to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare

```
func loadFrom<T: Decodable>(url: String, memberType: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
```

and call it

```
loadFrom(url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?completed=true", memberType: Todo.self) {response in
    ...
}
```

---

And rather than the unhandy *fatal errors* add a better result type to be able to return also the errors and catch the *bad URL* before calling the method

```
func loadFrom<T: Decodable>(url: URL, memberType: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<T,Error>) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, _, error in
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
        } else {
           completionHandler( Result{ try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)})
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `loadFrom(url:memberType:completionHandler:)` method,

**1.** Use **`T.Type`** instead of `T` as data type for `memberType`

**2.** Add **`@escaping`** to the `completionHandler`

```
func loadFrom<T: Decodable>(url: String, memberType: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping ((T?)->()))
```

Call the method like,

```
loadFrom(url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?completed=true", memberType: Todo.self) {response in
     ...
}
```

Also, add `return` in the `guard` statement,

```
guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
    completionHandler(nil)
    return //here...
}
```